# Python Regex to print (alphabet only) words with spaces and exclude non-ascii characters

Tags: python, regex

My python function definition is as follows:

```
def name_extractor(dirty_name):
    print Name
    clean_name = re.sub('\W'," ", dirty_name)
    print clean_name
```

The samples of dirty name contains:

```
(10) Johny Doe
Eric E. Shelby
(1) Chris Melton - ŗ≤ēŗ≤Ņŗ≤įŗ≤Ņŗ≤ēŗ≥ć ŗ≤ēŗ≥Äŗ≤įŗ≥ćŗ≤§ŗ≤Ņ
Jonas Alexander Bay
Christopher Rockstar - An awesome guy
Jones Collier
```

I want to the output to print just:

```
Johny Doe
Eric E. Shelby
Chris Melton
Jonas Alexander Bay
Christopher Rockstar
Jones Collier
```

How to tweak the regular expression to print names only as it is and exclude everything (the random characters or normal ascii characters) after "-"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for that. Split each line on `' - '` and then filter out the characters you don't want, stripping the extra whitespace:

```
>>> l = '''(10) Johny Doe
... Eric E. Shelby
... (1) Chris Melton - ŗ≤ēŗ≤Ņŗ≤įŗ≤Ņŗ≤ēŗ≥ć ŗ≤ēŗ≥Äŗ≤įŗ≥ćŗ≤§ŗ≤Ņ
... Jonas Alexander Bay
... Christopher Rockstar - An awesome guy
... Jones Collier'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in l:
...     print(''.join(c for c in line.split(' - ')[0] if c.isalpha() or c in ' .').strip())
...
Johny Doe
Eric E. Shelby
Chris Melton
Jonas Alexander Bay
Christopher Rockstar
Jones Collier
```

Comment: Same non-re answer here. beat me to it

Comment: this doesn't clearly correspond to the OPs question *How to tweak the regular expression*

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - The OP accepted this answer, so they were obviously looking for the correct result with any strategy rather than a wrong result with a wrong strategy, but thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude all non-ascii characters and all others that go after hyphen `-` - it would be enough to replace them with empty string `""`.
Short solution using specific regex pattern:

```
dirty_name = '''
(10) Johny Doe
Eric E. Shelby
(1) Chris Melton - ŗ≤ēŗ≤Ņŗ≤įŗ≤Ņŗ≤ēŗ≥ć ŗ≤ēŗ≥Äŗ≤įŗ≥ćŗ≤§ŗ≤Ņ
Jonas Alexander Bay
Christopher Rockstar - An awesome guy
Jones Collier'''

clean_name = '\n'.join(l.lstrip() for l in re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]|[\d()]| - .+\b(?=\n)', "", dirty_name).split('\n'))
print(clean_name)
```

The output:

```
Johny Doe
Eric E. Shelby
Chris Melton
Jonas Alexander Bay
Christopher Rockstar
Jones Collier
```

***Edit:*** removed left leading spaces cause @TigerhawkT3 is too *"space-sensitive"*(in his own religion)

*P.S.* `\x00-\x7f` is **ASCII** characters range

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output - you've got a leading space on a line.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, so? It becomes a completely wrong solution with that s**ty space?!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, perhaps, it's just your personal idea of "completeness"

Comment: The OP gave the output they were looking for, and your solution does not produce it. I don't think it's a matter of opinion; your answer quite clearly does not work (in addition to being complicated and unreadable).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, to strip the space - it's not a big problem. But you are making it as a huge problem, I suppose.

Comment: Actually, I just ran your code... there were no leading spaces, but there were lines like `Chris Melton - rerNrirNrerc rerrircr§rN` and `Christopher Rockstar - An awesome guy`. Would you consider that a "huge problem"? Did you even test your own code?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, >>> import re
>>> dirty_name = '''(10) Johny Doe
... Eric E. Shelby
... (1) Chris Melton - r?er?Nr?ir?Nr?er?c r?er?Ar?ir?cr?§r?N
... Jonas Alexander Bay
... Christopher Rockstar - An awesome guy
... Jones Collier'''
>>> clean_name = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]|[\d()]| - .+\b(?=\n)', "", dirty_name)
>>> print(clean_name.strip())
Johny Doe
Eric E. Shelby
 Chris Melton
Jonas Alexander Bay
Christopher Rockstar
Jones Collier
>>>

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, you have missed something in the input text, cause I have used the OP's text as it was, just copied it